# uwp-community-toolkit : GridView - Pb selection on usercontrol with CanDrag and DragStarting on MasterDetail

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop

I make a single page application with uwp community template, add a gridview with a templateitem and activate multiselection. There I add "CanDrag" and event "DragStarting" on the itemtemplate.

Result is : no selection when clic on stackpanel (in blue) or image include in the itemtemplate.

Any idea ?

My code, just add the grid to default main view plug on sampleorder.

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="detTemplate" x:DataType="model:SampleOrder">
        <StackPanel Height="64" Orientation="Horizontal"  CanDrag="True" DragStarting="Items_DragStarting" >
            <FontIcon Tag="{x:Bind HashIdentIcon}" FontSize="40" Glyph="{x:Bind SymbolAsChar}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <StackPanel Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Background="Aqua">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Company}" Tag="{x:Bind HashIdentTitle}" Style="{ThemeResource ListTitleStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Status}" Style="{StaticResource ListSubTitleStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid
    x:Name="ContentArea"
    Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="TitleRow" Height="48"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock
        x:Name="TitlePage"
        x:Uid="Main_Title"
        Style="{StaticResource PageTitleStyle}" />

    <Grid 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">

        <GridView x:Name="Lines" Background="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="False" MinHeight="150" 
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource detTemplate}" >
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
    <!--  Adaptive triggers  -->
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TitlePage.Margin" cu:Value="48,0,12,7" fcu:Value="0,0,12,7"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to minify your question. Like for example that VisualStateManager is irrelevant. You don't need to share all your code, just the relevant parts. You _should not_ upload your project and share a link. If that is needed then the question isn't supposed to be asked here in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the drag stuff on the template. Instead put it on the GridView.

```
<GridView AllowDrop="True" 
          CanDragItems="True"
          DragItemsStarting="OnDragItemsStarting"
          DragOver="OnDragOver"/>
```

Here are a couple of resources to help out:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt185571.aspx
- http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2015/8/23/drag-and-drop-in-uwp

Comment: I find my error, i use CanDrag property and not CanDragItems ... Thx